# How to do text matching in .srt file and get the timestamp of the line in which the text exists

Tags: python, regex, file, srt

The return value should be the start time of that sentence.

```
import re

key = input("ENTER THE KEY PHRASE")
file = open('tcs.srt','r')

for line in file.readlines():
    if re.search(r'^%s'%key, line, re.I):
        print(line)
```

for example :

> SERACH key : `milestone`
>
> to be found in:
>   `0:01:25,299 --> 0:01:31,099 one of the significant milestones and
>   great momentum in many of the areas that`
>
> `0:01:25,299` should be returned in seconds

Comment: Your input string is not clear.

Comment: i have edited...plz take a look now

Comment: The regex you need is r"\d{1}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\,\d{3}". You may convert that to timestamp later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.srt` files contains timestamps and subtitles. The time format is `hours:minutes:seconds,milliseconds`. Here is the function that returns the first timestamp in `hours:minutes:seconds,milliseconds --> hours:minutes:seconds,milliseconds` in seconds.

```py
import re

def return_seconds(line):
    timeValues = line[:line.index("-->")].strip().replace(",",":").split(":")
    timeValues = list(map(int, timeValues))
    hours_to_seconds = timeValues[0] * 3600
    minutes_to_seconds = timeValues[1] * 60
    seconds = timeValues[2]
    milliseconds_to_seconds = round(timeValues[3]/1000, 2)
    total_seconds = hours_to_seconds + minutes_to_seconds + seconds + milliseconds_to_seconds
    return total_seconds

key = input("ENTER THE KEY PHRASE")
file = open('tcs.srt','r')

previousLine = ""

for line in file.readlines():
    if key in line:
        print("Starting seconds at line is {}".format(return_seconds(previousLine)))
    previousLine = line
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, but nothing is being returned.

Comment: the thing is the timestamp is not in the same line of text, its in the previous line of every text, how shud i modify the code for that. Your help is appreciated

Comment: @AKASHV In that case we need to fetch the previous line. We can keep the previous line in a variable and then use it for calculation. Updated the answer.

Comment: there is still no output

Comment: @AKASHV Sorry, I thought your regex was working. It should be working as intended now. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.split` and instead of regex you can use `if key in line`

**Ex:**

```
import re

key = input("ENTER THE KEY PHRASE")
file = open('tcs.srt','r')

for line in file.readlines():
    if key in line:
        print(line.split()[0])
```

Comment: OUTPUT:                                              ENTER THE KEY PHRASE :milestone
one
again

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
text="0:01:25,299 --> 0:01:31,099 one of the significant milestones and great momentum in many of the areas that"
import re
print(re.findall(r"\d{1}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\,\d{3}",text))
```

Output:

```
['0:01:25,299', '0:01:31,099']
```